# How to add a component as a sibling to a directive in angular 8?

Tags: angular

```
   <div>
     <input type="text"/>
     <span class="drop-down-icon"></span>
   </div>
   <ul *ngIf="something">
     <li *ngFor="let item of list"></li>
   </ul>
```

In the above code, div element and its children are added from the directive, but I want the ul element to be added from the component, can it be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be achieve using the ElementRef you can add the DOM element from the component.
But if you want to add `*ngFor` directive to the ul then ul element will also created on the iteration.